# Recursively keeping count in Java - Simple

Tags: java, recursion, count, increment

I know that I'm overlooking something incredibly fundamental and elementary, but I need help with creating a mean function that, using only one parameter (the list containing the integers- in this case), calculates the mean of the given integers.

```
public static double mean (Cons lst) {
    int total = (Integer) lst.data;
    int count = //something to keep count through the recursion

    if(lst.next == null) {
        return total / count;
    }

    else return mean(lst.next); // return statement isn't correct, need help here as well
}
```

Any help would be great. If the easiest way to explain is by writing the method itself, then that'd be wonderful, but I'm just trying to figure out how to recursively keep a running count *without adding params*.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want the program to be recursive? Calculating the mean of an int array usually is done in a simple loop...

Comment: Why would you want to do this recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are developing your recursive mean function as a method of a Java Class. Why don't you declare your count and total local variables as attributes of that class?

```
class Mean {

    static int total = 0;
    static int count = 0;

    public static double mean (Cons lst) {
        total += (Integer) lst.data;
        count += 1;
        if(lst.next == null) {
            double ret = total/count;
            total = 0;
            count = 0;
            return ret;
        }
      return mean(lst.next); // return statement isn't correct, need help here as well
    }
}
```

Other option is to include "count" as a second parameter of your recursive method. If you don't want the user to pass more parameters use two methods: "mean" method, with one parameter (your list), should call the second method "recursiveMean(list, 0)" containing your implementation.

```
public static double mean (Cons lst) {
    return recursiveMean (lst, 0, 0)
}

public static double recursiveMean (Cons lst, int count, int total) {
    total += (Integer) lst.data;
    count += 1;
    if(lst.next == null) {
        return total / count;
    }
  return mean(lst.next,count,total); // return statement isn't correct, need help here as well
}
```

Nevertheless, I don't see why you are implementing a mean function as a recursive function unless it is some kind of educational exercise.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do it without a local variable, but there's just no way. Thought I was missing something, guess not. And yes, it is an edu exercise.